# Map Entity to different Tables based on certain condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have one Entity named Transaction and its related table in database is TAB_TRANSACTIONS. The whole system is working pretty fine; now a new requirement has came up in which the client has demanded that all the transactions older than 30 days should be moved to another archive table, e.g. TAB_TRANSACTIONS_HIST.

Currently as a work around I have given them a script scheduled to run every 24 hours, which simply moves the data from Source to Dest.

I was wondering is there any better solution to this using hibernate?

Can I fetch Transaction entities and then store them in TAB_TRANSACTIONS_HISTORY? I have looked at many similar questions but couldn't find a solution to that, any suggestions would help.

Comment: I guess such tasks are meant for the scheduler/script which you have already built

Comment: @nitin chhajer Yeah , i understand , but i didnt wanted to add another dependency and say if i want to schedule a job in quartz scheduler which will pull all the transactions and archive them ,

Comment: Why don't you write a simple HQL in the quartz scheduler job which can copy from one table to another.

Comment: @NitinChhajer That would be an awsome idea, great , but just for knowledge perspective , isn't there any way really to achieve it through hibernate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create a quartz scheduler for this task. Here is the `Job` for the scheduler

```
public class DatabaseBackupJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        Session session = cfg.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery("insert into Tab_Transaction_History(trans) select t.trans as trans from Tab_Transaction t where t.date < :date")
        .setParameter("date", reqDate);
        try{
           Trasaction t = session.beginTransaction();
           q.executeNonQuery();
           t.commit();
        } catch(Exception e){
        } finally {
           session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

P.S. hibernate doesnot provide a scheduler, so you cannot perform this activity using core hibernate and hence you need external APIs like quartz scheduler

Answer (score 1):

The solution you search may be achieved only if you rely on TWO different persistence context, I think.

A single persistence context maps entities to tables in a non-dynamic way, so you can't perform a "runtime-switch" from a mapped-table to another.
But you can create a different persistence context (or a parallel configuration in hibernate instead of using 2 different contexts), then load this new configuration in a different EntityManager, and perform all your tasks.

That's the only solution that comes to mind, at the moment. Really don't know if it's adequate...

Comment: thanks for the answer, so do you mean i create another hibernate configuration and session factory , may be at run time programatically, and then save the objects through that ?

Comment: Exactly. But I don't know if this suites your needs, and can be kinda complex ...at least, more than a simple "runtime-switch" :)

Comment: yeah , but the problem lies the same, how would i change my class definition , i mean i am mapping using annotations and am not sure how to map it to another table using runtime even, am sorry if am bieng too dumb to ask that

Comment: You can create a parallel mapping in xml :) so that you use your default config normally, then when needed you load the config xml with the new mapping in a DIFFERENT EntityManager. I may try mapping ONLY the entities you really need for the passage from a table to another. Consider that the new Manager won't know that the entities you have to persist belong to a different context: for that Manager they will be only simple POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea to run the script every 24 hours.
You could decrase the interval if you're not happy.

But if you already have a working script, where is your actual problem?
Checking the age of all transactions and move the ones older than 30 days to another list or map is the best way I think.

Comment: thanks for the answer, no the problem is that i have this app hosted and for the script i need another dedicated machine to be running or alternatively someone manually trigger the stuff at times, so was wondering if i could integrate it on the web app itself which will automatically run whenever configured or triggered

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of schedule mechanism. Either a thread that is woken up periodically, or some other trigger that is appropriate for you.

You can also use a bulk insert operation

```
Query q = session.createQuery(
"insert into TabTransactionHistory tth
(.....)
select .... from TabTransaction tt"
);
int createdObjects = q.executeUpdate();
```

(Replace ... with actual fields)

You can also use the "where clause" which can be used to trim down result on basis of how old the entries are.